# Prove linear mapping belongs to $L: l^{2}(\mathbb{R})^{\star}$ and find operator norm

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the linear mapping $L: l^{2}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$L({x_n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x_n}/(2^{n/2})$$ belongs to $L: l^{2}(\mathbb{R})^{\star}$. What is its operator norm?

$l^{2}(\mathbb{R})^{\star}$ is the dual space/conjugate space.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial that $L$ is linear, and by Hölder's inequality:
$$|L(x)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n/2^{n/2}|\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}|x_n|^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1/2^{n/2})^2\right)=\Vert x\Vert_2$$
So $L$ is bounded and $\Vert L\Vert\leq1$.

Moreover we claim that $\Vert L\Vert=1$, so it suffices to find $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in\ell^2$ s.t. $|L(x)|=\Vert x\Vert_2$. It is not hard to see that $x_n=1/2^{n/2}$ is the one we want.